# Mapping object in react to display values from Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble displaying results from an axis call. For some reason, and it may be minor, I am getting an error although I have consistently used the map function the same way on the results from the API call.

This is the response from the api call

```
[{"id":4,"cart_id":"6df311fb","customer_id":"1833b826","adults":2,"children":0,"total":400,"date":"2023-05-22T00:00:00.000Z","cash":true,"fulfilled":false,"paid":false,"created_at":"2023-05-06T20:27:06.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-05-06T20:27:06.000000Z"}]
```

This is the code I have. I confirmed via console.log(data) that data has the object.

```
{data ? ( data.map((data) => {
              return (
                  <div className="data" key={data.id}>
                    <h3>{data.adults}</h3>
                  </div>
              ); })) : (
                <h3>No data yet</h3>
            )}
```

The below is the error that I get

TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')

Comment: How did you define the data variable? Did you take it in a useState? There is slight error in data.map. you can do data.map((data) => .... // you're referencing as the same name data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const data = [
    { "id": 4, "cart_id": "6df311fb", "customer_id": "1833b826", "adults": 2, "children": 0, "total": 400, "date": "2023-05-22T00:00:00.000Z", "cash": true, "fulfilled": false, "paid": false, "created_at": "2023-05-06T20:27:06.000000Z", "updated_at": "2023-05-06T20:27:06.000000Z" }
  ]

  return (
    <div className='userInfo'>{data.length ? (data.map(item => {
      return (
        <div className="data" key={item.id}>
          <h3>{item.adults}</h3>
        </div>
      );
    })) : (
      <h3>No data yet</h3>
    )}</div>
  )
}
```